# Prevent the service from destroying when the activity finished

Tags: android, android-service

I have a `Service` called ***songs service*** and i used `bind service` to connect to this service.

The problem is simple when i click on back button it's become destroyed and this is not what i want.

I know if i use `startService()` the service will not destroy after i hit the back button but i can't get access to my service methods anymore.

Here  is my **Service**:

```
public class SongsService extends Service {
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private IBinder mBinder;
private String path = Values.songPlayerUrl;
static String playerUrl;
static public final int STOPPED = -1, PAUSED = 0, PLAYING = 1;
static String postId;
static String postType;
static String postTitle;
static String songName;
static String lowSongDownloadLink;
static String highSongDownloadLink;
static String coverUrl;
static String postLikes;
static String postDislikes;
static String postViews;
private int status;
private boolean taken;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mBinder = new MyBinder();
    setStatus(STOPPED);
}

public void take() {
    taken = true;
}

private void unTake() {
    synchronized (this) {
        taken = false;
        notifyAll();
    }
}

public String getPlayerUrl() {
    return playerUrl;
}

public void setPlayerUrl(String playerUrl) {
    this.playerUrl = playerUrl;
}

public String getPostId() {
    return postId;
}

public void setPostId(String postId) {
    this.postId = postId;
}

private void setStatus(int s) {
    status = s;
}

public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void playTrack() {
    if (status > STOPPED) {
        stop();
    }
    setPlayerUrl(Values.songPlayerUrl);
    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getPlayerUrl());
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mediaPlayer.start();
    setStatus(PLAYING);
    setPostId(Values.postId);
    postType = Values.postType;
    postTitle = Values.postTitle;
    songName = Values.songName;
    coverUrl = Values.coverUrl;
    postLikes = Values.postLikes;
    postDislikes = Values.postDislikes;
    postViews = Values.postViews;
    unTake();
}
public void play() {
    switch (status) {
        case STOPPED:
            playTrack();
            break;
        case PLAYING:
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            setStatus(PAUSED);
            break;
        case PAUSED:
            mediaPlayer.start();
            setStatus(PLAYING);
            break;
    }
    unTake();
}
public void stop() {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.reset();
    setStatus(STOPPED);
    unTake();
}
public int getCurrentTrackProgress() {
    if (status > STOPPED) {
        return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

public int getCurrentTrackDuration() {
    if (status > STOPPED) {
        return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
public void seekTrack(int p) {
    if (status > STOPPED) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(p);
        unTake();
    }
}
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return mBinder;
}

public boolean onUnBind(Intent intent) {
    return super.onUnbind(intent);
}

public class MyBinder extends Binder {
    public SongsService getService() {
        return SongsService.this;
    }
}

public static String formatTrackDuration(int d) {
    String min = Integer.toString((d/1000)/60);
    String sec = Integer.toString((d/1000)%60);
    if (sec.length() == 1) sec = "0"+sec;
    return min+":"+sec;
}
}
```

and here is my **Activity**

```
public class Songs_Single extends AppMenu {

ListView lv;
ImageView cover;
ImageView playBtn;
ImageView prevBtn;
ImageView nextBtn;
SeekBar songSeekBar;
SeekBar volumeSeekBar;
TextView actionbar_Title;
TextView actionbar_Subtitle;
TextView SongCurrentTime;
TextView SongDuration;
AudioManager audioManager;
PlayerService playerService;
private UiRefresher uiRefresher;
private Timer progressRefresher;
private int playerStatus;
SongsService songsService;
ArrayList<Songs_Single_ContentSetter> postList;
Songs_Single_ArrayAdapter adapter;
TextView lvFtr;
boolean mVal = true;
private String term_id = "";
int lvCount = 0;
int count;
private ArrayList<String> term_ids = Values.postTags;
private String[] myNum = {"135","138","174","424","231","500","581","582","3132","8126"};
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View contentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.songs_single, null, false);
    drawerLayout.addView(contentView, 0);
    ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.songs_single_header, lv,
            false);

    postList = new ArrayList<>();
    adapter = new Songs_Single_ArrayAdapter(Songs_Single.this, R.layout.songs_single_row, postList);
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Songs_Single_listView);
    lvFtr = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    lvFtr.setText("loading");
    lv.addHeaderView(header);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    if (term_ids != null ) {
        term_ids.removeAll(Arrays.asList(myNum));
        for (int m = 0; m < term_ids.size(); m++) {
            term_id += "&tax_query[0][terms][" + m + "]=" + term_ids.get(m);
        }
    }
    new GetData().execute();
    progressRefresher = new Timer();
    final ImageView logo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.actionbar_logo);
    logo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    cover = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Songs_Single_Cover);
    actionbar_Title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_Title);
    actionbar_Title.setSelected(true);
    actionbar_Subtitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actionbar_Subtitle);
    actionbar_Subtitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    playBtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Songs_Single_Controls_Controls_PlayBtn);
    nextBtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Songs_Single_Controls_Controls_NextBtn);
    nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
    prevBtn = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Songs_Single_Controls_Controls_PrevBtn);
    songSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.Songs_Single_Controls_SeekBar_SeekBar);
    volumeSeekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.Songs_Single_Controls_VolumeBar_VolumeBar);
    SongCurrentTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Songs_Single_Controls_SongCurrentTime);
    SongDuration = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Songs_Single_Controls_SongDuration);
    if (Values.coverUrl != ""){
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Values.coverUrl).into(cover);
    }
    if (Values.postLikes != "")
        actionbar_Subtitle.setText(Values.postLikes+" Likes | "+Values.postDislikes+" Dislikes | "+Values.postViews+" Plays" );
    if ((Values.postTitle != "") && (Values.songName != ""))
        actionbar_Title.setText(Values.postTitle+" - "+Values.songName);


    playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!(Values.postId.equals(songsService.getPostId()))) {
                songsService.stop();
            }
            songsService.play();
        }
    });
    songSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, final int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            if (Values.postId.equals(songsService.getPostId())){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        SongCurrentTime.setText(songsService.formatTrackDuration(progress));
                    }
                });
            if (fromUser) {
                songsService.seekTrack(progress);
            }
        }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    progressRefresher.schedule(new TimerTask() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (playerStatus == songsService.PLAYING) {
                refreshTrack();
            }
        }
    }, 0, 500);

    audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    int maxVolume = audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    int currentVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    volumeSeekBar.setMax(maxVolume);
    volumeSeekBar.setProgress(currentVolume);
    volumeSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress, 0);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            position = position-1;
            if (postList.get(position).getPostType().equals("songs")) {
                Intent songs = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Songs_Single.class);
                Values.postTitle = postList.get(position).getPostTitle();
                Values.postId = postList.get(position).getPostId();
                Values.postType = postList.get(position).getPostType();
                Values.songName = postList.get(position).getSongName();
                Values.coverUrl = postList.get(position).getCoverUrl();
                Values.postLikes = postList.get(position).getPostLikes();
                Values.postDislikes = postList.get(position).getPostDislikes();
                Values.postViews = postList.get(position).getPostViews();
                Values.songPlayerUrl = postList.get(position).getSongPlayerUrl();
                Values.postTags = postList.get(position).getPostTags();
                startActivity(songs);
            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Intent intent= new Intent(this, SongsService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                   IBinder binder) {
        SongsService.MyBinder b = (SongsService.MyBinder) binder;
        songsService = b.getService();
        uiRefresher = new UiRefresher();
        (new Thread(uiRefresher)).start();
    }

    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName className) {
    }
};

private void refreshTrack() {
    if (Values.postId.equals(songsService.getPostId())) {
        final int progress = songsService.getCurrentTrackProgress(), max = songsService.getCurrentTrackDuration();
        final String durationText = songsService.formatTrackDuration(songsService.getCurrentTrackDuration()), progressText = songsService.formatTrackDuration(songsService.getCurrentTrackProgress());
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                SongDuration.setText(durationText);
                SongCurrentTime.setText(progressText);
                songSeekBar.setMax(max);
                songSeekBar.setProgress(progress);
            }

        });
    }
}

private void refreshButtons() {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (Values.postId.equals(songsService.getPostId())) {
                switch (playerStatus) {
                    case PlayerService.PLAYING:
                        playBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause);
                        break;
                    default:
                        playBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play);
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private class UiRefresher implements Runnable {

    private boolean done = false;

    public void done() {
        done = true;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!done) {
            synchronized (songsService) {
                playerStatus = songsService.getStatus();
                refreshTrack();
                refreshButtons();
                songsService.take();
                try {
                    songsService.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    String postId = "";
    String postType = "";
    String postTitle = "";
    String songName = "";
    String artistName = "";
    String songPlayerUrl = "";
    String lowSongDownloadLink = "";
    String highSongDownloadLink = "";
    String coverUrl = "";
    String songLyric = "";
    String postLikes = "0";
    String postDislikes = "0";
    String postViews = "0";
    String postDownloadsCount = "0";
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        lv.addFooterView(lvFtr);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        String results = "";
        mVal = true;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://paradi3emusic.com/?json=get_posts&post_type=songs&post__not_in[]=" + Values.postId + "&tax_query[0][taxonomy]=post_tag&tax_query[0][field]=id" + term_id);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if(code==200){
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                    results += line;


                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(results);
                count = jsono.getInt("count");
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("posts");
                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length() ; i++) {
                    Songs_Single_ContentSetter content1 = new Songs_Single_ContentSetter();
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    postId = object.getString("id");
                    postType = object.getString("type");
                    JSONObject attachments = object.getJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                    JSONObject attachments0 = attachments.getJSONObject("tumb");
                    coverUrl = attachments0.getString("url");
                    JSONObject customFields = object.getJSONObject("custom_fields");
                    if (customFields.has("ozy_post_plays_count")) {
                        JSONArray postViewsVal = customFields.getJSONArray("ozy_post_plays_count");
                        postViews = postViewsVal.getString(0);
                    }
                    if (customFields.has("like")) {
                        JSONArray postLikesVal = customFields.getJSONArray("like");
                        postLikes = postLikesVal.getString(0);
                    }
                    if (customFields.has("dislike")) {
                        JSONArray postDislikesVal = customFields.getJSONArray("dislike");
                        postDislikes = postDislikesVal.getString(0);
                    }
                    if (customFields.has("download_count")) {
                        JSONArray postDownloadsCountVal = customFields.getJSONArray("download_count");
                        postDownloadsCount = postDownloadsCountVal.getString(0);
                    }
                    if (customFields.has("playlist")) {
                        JSONArray playlist = customFields.getJSONArray("playlist");
                        if (playlist.getJSONArray(0) != null) {
                            JSONArray playlist0 = playlist.getJSONArray(0);
                            JSONObject playlistObjs = playlist0.getJSONObject(0);
                            postTitle = playlistObjs.getString("title");
                            artistName = postTitle.substring(0, postTitle.indexOf("-") + 1);
                            songName = postTitle.substring(postTitle.indexOf("-") + 1);
                            songPlayerUrl = playlistObjs.getString("mp3");
                            highSongDownloadLink = playlistObjs.getString("buy_link_a");
                            lowSongDownloadLink = playlistObjs.getString("buy_link_b");
                            songLyric = playlistObjs.getString("lyric").equals("") ? "Sorry,no lyrics found,submit your lyric by contact us" : playlistObjs.getString("lyric");
                        }
                    }
                    content1.setPostTitle(artistName.replace(" -",""));
                    content1.setSongName(songName);
                    content1.setSongPlayerUrl(songPlayerUrl);
                    content1.setHighSongDownloadLink(highSongDownloadLink);
                    content1.setLowSongDownloadLink(lowSongDownloadLink);
                    content1.setSongLyric(songLyric);
                    content1.setPostViews(postViews);
                    content1.setPostLikes(postLikes);
                    content1.setPostDislikes(postDislikes);
                    content1.setPostId(postId);
                    content1.setPostType(postType);
                    content1.setCoverUrl(coverUrl);
                    content1.setPostDownloadsCount(postDownloadsCount);
                    postList.add(content1);
                }
                in.close();
                return true;
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        lv.removeFooterView(lvFtr);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(postList.size() < 30) {
            new GetMoreData().execute("http://paradi3emusic.com/?json=get_posts&post_type=songs&orderby=rand&no_found_rows=true&count=" + (postList.size() - 30) + "&post__not_in[]=" + Values.postId);
        }
        if(!result)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unable to get data please check yor connection and try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

class GetMoreData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    String postId = "";
    String postType = "";
    String postTitle = "";
    String songName = "";
    String artistName = "";
    String songPlayerUrl = "";
    String lowSongDownloadLink = "";
    String highSongDownloadLink = "";
    String coverUrl = "";
    String songLyric = "";
    String postLikes = "0";
    String postDislikes = "0";
    String postViews = "0";
    String postDownloadsCount = "0";
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        lv.addFooterView(lvFtr);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        String results = "";
        mVal = true;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            int code = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

            if(code==200){
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());

                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                    results += line;


                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(results);
                count = jsono.getInt("count");
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("posts");
                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length() ; i++) {
                    Songs_Single_ContentSetter content1 = new Songs_Single_ContentSetter();
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    postId = object.getString("id");
                    postType = object.getString("type");
                    JSONObject attachments = object.getJSONObject("thumbnail_images");
                    JSONObject attachments0 = attachments.getJSONObject("tumb");
                    coverUrl = attachments0.getString("url");
                    JSONObject customFields = object.getJSONObject("custom_fields");
                    if (customFields.has("ozy_post_plays_count")) {
                        JSONArray postViewsVal = customFields.getJSONArray("ozy_post_plays_count");
                        postViews = postViewsVal.getString(0);
                    }
                    if (customFields.has("like")) {
                        JSONArray postLikesVal = customFields.getJSONArray("like");
                        postLikes = postLikesVal.getString(0);
                    }
                    if (customFields.has("dislike")) {
                        JSONArray postDislikesVal = customFields.getJSONArray("dislike");
                        postDislikes = postDislikesVal.getString(0);
                    }
                    if (customFields.has("download_count")) {
                        JSONArray postDownloadsCountVal = customFields.getJSONArray("download_count");
                        postDownloadsCount = postDownloadsCountVal.getString(0);
                    }
                    if (customFields.has("playlist")) {
                        JSONArray playlist = customFields.getJSONArray("playlist");
                        if (playlist.getJSONArray(0) != null) {
                            JSONArray playlist0 = playlist.getJSONArray(0);
                            JSONObject playlistObjs = playlist0.getJSONObject(0);
                            postTitle = playlistObjs.getString("title");
                            artistName = postTitle.substring(0, postTitle.indexOf("-") + 1);
                            songName = postTitle.substring(postTitle.indexOf("-") + 1);
                            songPlayerUrl = playlistObjs.getString("mp3");
                            highSongDownloadLink = playlistObjs.getString("buy_link_a");
                            lowSongDownloadLink = playlistObjs.getString("buy_link_b");
                            songLyric = playlistObjs.getString("lyric").equals("") ? "Sorry,no lyrics found,submit your lyric by contact us" : playlistObjs.getString("lyric");
                        }
                    }
                    content1.setPostTitle(artistName.replace(" -",""));
                    content1.setSongName(songName);
                    content1.setSongPlayerUrl(songPlayerUrl);
                    content1.setHighSongDownloadLink(highSongDownloadLink);
                    content1.setLowSongDownloadLink(lowSongDownloadLink);
                    content1.setSongLyric(songLyric);
                    content1.setPostViews(postViews);
                    content1.setPostLikes(postLikes);
                    content1.setPostDislikes(postDislikes);
                    content1.setPostId(postId);
                    content1.setPostType(postType);
                    content1.setCoverUrl(coverUrl);
                    content1.setPostDownloadsCount(postDownloadsCount);
                    postList.add(content1);
                }
                in.close();
                return true;
            }

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        lv.removeFooterView(lvFtr);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        if(!result)
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Unable to get data please check yor connection and try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}


}
```

What should i do ?

Comment: use `"started & bound service"` pattern

Comment: go to this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) and ^F `Binding to a Started Service`

Comment: @pskink this is exactly what i did but as i said the service become destroy after i hit the back button of the device

Comment: post your activity code then

Comment: it's a lot :) but i will send it

Comment: post only code related to your `Service`

Comment: sry but i posted all

Comment: i dont see any call of `startService`...

Comment: i use bind service. i said if i use start service then i can't get access to it's methods

Comment: i bind to my service it's in onStart @pskink

Comment: so read the section `"Binding to a Started Service"` again

Comment: i think you didn't understand my question correctly@pskink

Comment: did you notice `"As discussed in the Services document, you can create a service that is both started and bound."` ?

Comment: yes but please tell me what i have to do

Comment: what you have to do is to follow two steps described in section `"Binding to a Started Service"`, did you read it?

Comment: look you mean first start service then bind it? @pskink

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which one is a good practice or not but you can achieve it by two way

1. you can use service without binding it with activity class and use an interface inside service class which will be implemented by activity to get the callback and also to access the methods of service you created.
2. You can use Local broadcast manager and can send the broadcast from activity to service and vice versa to access service operation from activity and activity operation from service.

Let me know if you need any code snippet for this

Comment: pskink way solved my problem. I started my service first then bind to it but please tell me more about first way.